# How can I speed up my for loop that deletes rows meeting certain criteria?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working through data in Google sheets, attempting to delete rows based on a particular column condition. I have 900 or so rows of data to read. I set up a for loop that reads in column 11 for each row, to determine whether or not it contains the word "Rejected". If it does NOT, I want to delete the row. The script works as is but unfortunately, it takes a few minutes to process. I'm worried as I add in additional lines of code, it will eventually timeout at the 6 minute cap. Any suggestions on how to speed this up?

```
function Script2(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("To Review");
    var range = sheet.getActiveRange();

    // delete the first three rows that appear
    var start, end;
    start = 1;
    end = 3;
    sheet.deleteRows(start,end);
    sheet.setFrozenRows(1);

    // delete any rows that are not Rejected
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var counter = lastRow
    for(var i=0;i<lastRow-1;i++){
        var status = sheet.getRange(counter,11).getValue();
        if(status!='Rejected'){
            sheet.deleteRow(counter)
        }
        counter = counter-1
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't delete rows at all. Use `getValues()` and `setValues()`. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  best practices.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56396168/

Answer (score 0):

```
function Script3() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('To Review');
  var sr=4;
  var rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vs=rg.getValues();
  var kA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vs.length;i++) {
    if(vs[i][10]=='Rejected') {
      kA.push(vs[i]);
    }
  }
  sh.clear({contentsOnly:true});
  sh.getRange(1,1,kA.length,kA[0].length).setValue(kA);
}
```