# Is there a way to speed up .deleteRow()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script to copy (and delete) rows from a spreadsheet if they fulfill certain criteria, but theres an issue, ive noticed that .deleteRow() is VERY VERY VERY SLOW, and im wondering if theres a way to speed up what i gotta do (delete a bunch of non-contiguous rows after ive copied them) because currently the script is timing out before it can delete all the rows its supposed to.

```
function copyIfConditions() {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sourceSpreadSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("NUEVOS INGRESOS Y EXPEDIENTES EN TRAMITE");//Changed sheet name
  const activeSpreadSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("CASOS ARCHIVADOS/FINALIZADOS");
  const spA = ["Finalizado_Archivado", "Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_conexidad", "Remitida_UACF", "Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_por_recusacion", "Remitida_a_otro_Juzgado_por_cuestion_de_turno", "Remitida_a_otros_fueros"];
  let ingresos_lastRow = sourceSpreadSheet.getLastRow()
  let ingresos_lastColumn = sourceSpreadSheet.getLastColumn()
  let archivados_lastRow = activeSpreadSheet.getLastRow()

  if (ingresos_lastRow == 1) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('No data!', 'End of script ️');
    return;
  }
  const vs = sourceSpreadSheet.getRange(2, 1, ingresos_lastRow - 1, ingresos_lastColumn).getValues();
  const archiveData = [];
//  const deleteRowsData = [];

  let d = 0;//delete counter
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (~spA.indexOf(r[34])) {
      archiveData.push(r);
      //deleteRowsData.push(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  });


  activeSpreadSheet.getRange(archivados_lastRow + 1, 1, archiveData.length, archiveData[0].length).setValues(archiveData);
  for (let i = 0;i in deleteRowsData;i++){
  //sourceSpreadSheet.deleteRow(deleteRowsData[i])
  };
  console.log(deleteRowsData);

}
```

Code used to be a bit different, simply deleting the row like this after doing `archiveData.push()`

```
    if (~spA.indexOf(r[34])) {
      archiveData.push(r);
      sourceSpreadSheet.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
```

As you can imagine, that was even worse.
Basically, is there a way to make it so deleting those rows is faster so i dont fall victim to Google's execution time limit?

Comment: Try [batching up contiguous rows in the non-contiguous range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395779/why-is-my-apps-script-deletion-loop-running-so-slowly-can-i-improve-performance) or use [sheets api](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fsheets%2Fapi%2Freference%2Frest%2Fv4%2Fspreadsheets%2Frequest%23DeleteDimensionRequest)

Comment: You can make array row need delete and use code:var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['4:4', '6:10', '12:15','17:17']).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());

Comment: This question is being discussed at [community chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54866333#54866333)